# setting or changing the default ip address

Tags: suse, network-interface

I have a SUSE server and recently added a second IP address (ending in .159) by editing the config file below. It works, however now all the services on the machine are using the new address when making connections. Example: the nagios service now makes requests from the new IP address, and I want to use the old address (ending in .160) for all outbound connections. Is there a way to set a default IP address (ending in .160) for outbound connections? I'm just using the command line, no KDE available.

Here's my eth config file:

```
admin1@server1:/etc/sysconfig/network# more ifcfg-eth2
BOOTPROTO='static'
BROADCAST=''
ETHTOOL_OPTIONS=''
IPADDR='192.168.100.160/24'
MTU=''
NAME='79c970 [PCnet32 LANCE]'
NETWORK=''
REMOTE_IPADDR=''
STARTMODE='auto'
USERCONTROL='no'
IPADDR_external='207.47.100.160/24'
LABEL_external='external'
IPADDR1='192.168.100.159/24'
IPADDR1_external='207.47.100.159/24'
```

Here is the output of ip route show:

```
admin1@server1:/etc# ip route show
207.47.100.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 207.47.100.159
192.168.100.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.100.160
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth2  scope link
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  scope link
default via 192.168.100.1 dev eth2
```

Comment: What is the output of `ip route`?

Comment: Strange. I would expect `src 192.168.100.160` to cause `.160` to be the default source address.

Comment: I think the problem may be that first line -- how do I change the external route to also come from .160?

Comment: Have a look at `man 5 routes`. It says "All options (except of to, via and dev used in columns 1-4) of the ip route add command shall be supported.". Unfortunately the examples don't cover this case. But you may try to add `src 207.47.100.160` there.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I sort of figured out a solution -- Hauke, thanks for putting me on the right track. After comparing the ifcfg file with another, similar server that is routing as expected, I changed the names of my IPADDR suffixes. I have a feeling that when the routes are automatically created there is some sort of alpha sorting going on, and the "_external" suffix was sorting itself in a way I didn't desire.

The new file:

```
admin1@server1:/etc/sysconfig/network# more ifcfg-eth2
BOOTPROTO='static'
BROADCAST=''
ETHTOOL_OPTIONS=''
IPADDR='192.168.100.160/24'
MTU=''
NAME='79c970 [PCnet32 LANCE]'
NETWORK=''
REMOTE_IPADDR=''
STARTMODE='auto'
USERCONTROL='no'
IPADDR_0='207.47.100.160/24'
LABEL_0='external'
IPADDR_1='192.168.100.159/24'
IPADDR_2='207.47.100.159/24'
```

and the route output is now:

```
admin1@server1:/etc# ip route show
207.47.100.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 207.47.100.160
192.168.100.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.100.160
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth2  scope link
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  scope link
default via 192.168.100.1 dev eth2
```

After running some tests on my clients I can see that the .160 address is now being used for outbound connections.

I'm not sure if this configuration is considered "best practices", but I'll take it. Thanks again.